# HDF5 write fails even on OpenMP critical section

Tags: c++, openmp, hdf5

I've been looking to write a big 4-dimensional HDF5 file where the values are computed in parallel and written in mutual exclusion.

This is a minimal working example of my problem.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <omp.h>
#include "H5Cpp.h"
using namespace H5;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    H5File file("out.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

    const uint F_RANK = 4;
    const uint M_RANK = 3;

    const uint D = 8;
    const uint MD = 2;
    std::vector<hsize_t> fdim = {D, D, 6, 1024};
    std::vector<hsize_t> count = {1, 1, 6, 1024};
    std::vector<hsize_t> mdim = {MD, 6, 1024};

    float fillvalue = -1.0;
    DSetCreatPropList plist;
    plist.setFillValue(PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, &fillvalue);

    DataSpace fspace(F_RANK, fdim.data());
    DataSet dataset = file.createDataSet("data", PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, fspace, plist);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        uint id = omp_get_thread_num();
        std::vector<hsize_t> start(F_RANK, 0);
        DataSpace private_fspace = dataset.getSpace();
        DataSpace private_mspace(M_RANK, mdim.data());
        private_mspace.selectAll();
        std::cout << "THREAD " << id << " STARTS" << std::endl;
        #pragma omp for ordered schedule(static)
        for (uint b = 0; b < D*D / MD; b++)
        {
            // Assume this is an expensive computation
            std::vector<float> data(MD*6*1024, b);
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                private_fspace.selectNone();
                std::cout << "THREAD " << id << " SELECTED NONE" << std::endl;

                // Store batch
                for (uint p = 0; p < MD; p++)
                {
                    start[0] = b / (D*D) + p;
                    start[1] = p;
                    private_fspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_OR, count.data(), start.data());
                    std::cout << "THREAD " << id << " SELECTED " << start[0] << ' ' << start[1] << std::endl;
                }

                std::cout << "ABOUT TO WRITE " << private_fspace.getSelectNpoints() << std::endl;
                dataset.write(data.data(), PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, private_mspace, private_fspace);
                private_fspace.selectNone();
            }
            std::cout << "WRITTEN" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm compiling it using `h5c++ example.cpp -fopenmp`.

When run, there are many possible errors that can happen, some are Segmentation faults, others are aborts and even bus errors. 
There's even some HDF5 library errors like these

```
HDF5: infinite loop closing library
    L,T_top,P,P,Z,FD,E,SL,FL,FL,.....
```

Sometimes it will fail before writing anything, sometimes it will finish without any errors. Of course, it only fails when `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is set to more than 1, so the problem is in the parallelism. However, I've set all relevant variables I could as private for each process, and everything happens within a critical section, so I don't see how this is failing.

Debugging on GDB reveals HDF5 may fail on the DataSet::getSpace()  with a segmentation fault, but there are so many ways it can fail I'd say the problem is more general than this.

Comment: Could that be a stack size-related issue? Did you try playing with `OMP_STACKSIZE`?

Comment: I didn't know that variable. It fails sooner if I set it to the minimum of 16K, but bigger values don't fix the issue.

Comment: Facing something similar now, and I am only reading from read-only opened HDF5 file. Even if I fence the entire inner loop in `#pragma omp critical`, it will crash. :/

Comment: I don't think this will be the case for you, but what I did in the end is separate the threads into workers and a writer and then the critical section consisted of workers writing to a queue the writer would read to then write to the hdf5 file. If that makes sense :)